# Docker compose volumes invalid characters

Tags: ubuntu, docker, lighttpd

Unable to start container with docker-compose up

```
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER Parzee info@parzee.com

# Install Components.

# Update the repository
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
# Install necessary tools
RUN apt-get install -y nano vim wget dialog net-tools
RUN apt-get install lighttpd -y
RUN apt-get install php5-common php5-cgi php5 -y
RUN lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php
RUN update-rc.d -f lighttpd disable
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/utils/security/des

ADD lighttpd.conf /etc/lighttpd/

VOLUME ["/var/log/lighttpd"]

RUN ls -al /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

RUN /usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

EXPOSE 8083
```

docker-compose.yml

```
lighttpd:
  image: parzee/lighttpd
  ports: 
    - "8083:8083"
  volumes:
    - volumes/log:/var/log/lighttpd
```

When I run:

```
docker run -h lighttpd -p 8083:8083 -d -v `pwd`/volumes/log:/var/log/lighttpd -t parzee/lighttpd
```

my container starts fine, but with **docker-compose up** I get the following error:

```
Creating lighttpd_lighttpd_1
ERROR: volumes/log includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed
```

This is the file structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── lighttpd.conf
└── volumes
    ├── etc
    │   └── lighttpd
    │       └── lighttpd.conf
    └── log

4 directories, 4 files
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The yaml is quite picky on docker compose.
Make sure the path is absolute (for the host side) and contains no trailing spaces.

```
"- volumes/log:/var/log/lighttpd "
```

Should be

```
"- /host/path/volumes/log:/var/log/lighttpd"
```

Without the quotes!  I put those in to highlight the problem.

If you really need relative paths consider using [crane](https://github.com/michaelsauter/crane) instead of docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

To use relative paths in `volumes` section, you've to add `./`, e.g.

```
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/log:/var/log/lighttpd
```

Or from the command-line, like:

```
docker run -v $PWD/volumes/log:/var/log/lighttpd ...
```